# What 1995-1997 cartoon had robots manned by children fighting big aliens?

Tags: story-identification

The show was about an aggressive alien thing that came from outer space and infected the humans. The people started killing each other and the only way that they could be stopped was with alien robots that they discovered. These robots were manned by children, but there were also big nasty aliens and it was very graphic for something that showed on TV.

I want to find this so that I can watch it again, as I liked it.

Comment: The [tag:sy-fy] tag is specifically for shows that aired on the Sy-Fy (SciFi) cable channel. Is that where you saw it, or did you mean to tag it as [tag:science-fiction-genre]?

Comment: What country were you in when you saw this show? That will help us narrow down what shows were on-air during the years you specified.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of the humans being infected, this sounds very much like [Neon Genesis Evangelion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_%28anime%29), an anime that first aired from October 1995 to March 1996.

The story was about a group of children who battled invading alien "Angels" by piloting giant "Evangelion" robots.  There were some pretty mature themes included in the story, from the episodes that I watched.

Comment: I don't think so, apart from the mecha riding children nothing matches. And kids piloting mechas are practically their own trope in anime.

Comment: @SystemDown Well, in addition to the kids piloting the mechas, there was the time frame, the big nasty aliens from outer space, the graphic content, and the fact that the only hope was the mechas which were alien robots that they had discovered.

Comment: The Angels didn't infect the people though. That sounds like a big part of the OP's story.

Comment: @Xantec Yep, that'd definitely a major difference. However, the rest of the details were close enough that I felt it worth a chance that maybe there was some haziness to the memories, or possibly a conflation with a separate title.

Comment: True. If they maybe mixed Evangelion with Blue Gender that came out a couple years later, they might've come up with the given details.